# lightning:dualListbox is throwing script error on option selection

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, lightning-duallistbox

Below is my logic:

```
<aura:attribute name="selectedValues" type="List" />
<lightning:dualListbox name="languages"
                           label= "Select Languages"
                           sourceLabel="Available"
                           selectedLabel="Selected"
                           fieldLevelHelp="Select your preferred languages"
                           options="{!v.options}"
                           onchange="{! c.handleChange }"/>
```

Controller:

**arr holds the values:**
Tue Jul 07 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
Wed Jul 08 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
Thu Jul 09 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    opts.push({
        label: i,
        value: arr[i]
    });
}
component.set("v.options", opts);

handleChange: function (component, event) {
        // This will contain an array of the "value" attribute of the selected options
        var selectedOptionValue = event.getParam("value");
        component.set("v.selectedValues", selectedOptionValue);
    },
```

I am unable to select a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was not sending a string value to the label and value.
I converted the label and value using `.toString()` , the function of JavaScript.
This resolved my issue. Below is the correction in the code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    opts.push({
        label: i.toString(),
        value: arr[i].toString()
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

used `cmp` in your `handleChange` function but  inside function your using `component`
make consistency in both places.

```
handleChange: function (cmp, event) {
    // This will contain an array of the "value" attribute of the selected options
    var selectedOptionValue = event.getParam("value");
    cmp.set("v.selectedValues", selectedOptionValue);
},
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction. It worked. That was a silly mistake...

Comment: The script error is resolved, but still, I am not able to select the options. @sdandamud

Comment: i believe your options list is not correct format, can you put console.log(selectedOptionValue) and console.log(component.get("v.options")) see what format is coming